# Using webhost as proxy for specific website only

Tags: php, proxy

I have a Raspberry Pi which hosts some dynamic files. I want to keep external access to my Pi to an absolute minimum and I've come up with a clunky solution.

I have a website and I've told my router to block all external access to my Pi except for my webhost server's IP address. A PHP script on my website copies the relevant HTML files and images from the Pi to my webspace, then displays those files when I externally load the PHP script. However I'd like to improve this method by essentially using my webhost server as a proxy but only in order to access my Pi.

Other than setting up a web proxy on my webspace (which has risks as it could potentially be used by people for other things), is there a way I can set up a PHP script that reads the relevant files from the Pi (using the server's IP address) and then displays them to the end-user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a **reverse** proxy.
Have a look at this: http://techzinger.blogspot.ca/2007/07/writing-reverse-proxy-in-php5.html